# Reevaluate historical lock on "What would you change about C# if you could?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, locked-question

After five years, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2815/ still has only 5.5k views. It has 57 "answers" which amount to a poll of feature requests and ideas for a rather old version of C#.

Many of these are outdated and wrong now.  There are numerous other, better written (and updated) "what don't I like about C#" blog posts out there.

The long term value of the post and its negligible at best on this site in this format.

Please delete it (or unlock it so that others can delete it).

Comment: Deletion sounds good.

Comment: Hm, if memory serves this was locked during one of the massive cleanups of old, to avoid adding even more drama to the process (_Eeek! How dare you delete a question with 43 upvotes!_). I don't see a reason to keep it around anymore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw no reason at all for this to still exist and now it doesn't

Comment: +1 'cause I appreciate your work.